# Is it safe to use a computer with the case open?

Tags: cpu

My friend told me that system won't catch heat so fast if computer case is is opened. I decided to use a computer with the case open. Is that safe ?

It's an i3 processor computer with 4 GB RAM. Computer case is iBall.

Open means only one side of the case is opened.

Comment: A decent computer is designed to run with the case in place and not overheat. Is your computer overheating?  If so, determine why (dirt, fan error, some heavy duty software that taxes the CPU).

Comment: Processor = CPU. There's no such thing as CPU case. You mean a computer case.

Comment: It depends on the airflow efficiency of the case. In theory taking the side off will ruin the carefully designed airflow. In practice most PC cases are of such abysmal design that there is no significant difference. See https://superuser.com/a/1529892/347380 for some examples.

Comment: I would start with cleaning all the dust inside of your case and change CPU thermal paste. It is not that safe to run your computer with case opened, IMO.

Answer (score 1):

> My friend told me that system won't catch heat so fast if computer case is is opened.

Computer cases are designed to route airflow where it is needed. So long as the fans are working as intended and the inside is reasonable free from dust accumulation, the cooling system should be expected to work best with the case closed.