# i7 9700k running up to 100 degrees celcius

Tags: cpu, fan, cooling, temperature, overheating

I have an i7 9700k cooled with an ARCTIC Freezer 34 eSports DUO in a Corsair Carbide Series SPEC-04 Tempered Glass (1x 120mm fan at the front).

I remounted the cooler once, reapplied fresh thermal paste and I have the fans mounted complementary to each other, so they pull air in on one side and push air out on the other side towards the rear end of the PC. The problem is that while playing games such as Call of Duty Modern Warfare the temperatures are rising up to 99°C (measured with HWInfo64).

I did a little research on the CPU cooler and it is mostly desrcribed as sufficient for the i7 9700k. I could imagine that it might be the bad airflow in the case, as the heat kinda stacks up, but it is really weird since the case is really open at the rear end at the top rear end.

The GPU temperatures rise up to 85°C with 96°C at the memory junction and 102°C hotspot temperature, which I am not sure about whether this is fine or not.

Does anybody have some experience or tips for me on this issue and could the CPU have possibly already taken damage from running at such high temperatures?

Comment: I'm a bit confused about your fan setup. You have the one intake, and the fans on the CPU cooler doing a pull, push. Do you have another rear or top fan that is removing the hot air?

Comment: No, but the case is really open at the rear end, so I thought the heat could just rise into the air,  out of the case, but maybe that is naive to think. I guess a rear fan might be necessary no?

Comment: If your GPU is reaching 85°C and your CPU is reaching almost 100°C you clearly have an airflow problem.

Comment: Are your fans even turning at "correct" speeds?  Are you monitoring the speeds?

Comment: BTW, pulling hot air out is *usually* more important than pushing fresh air in.

Comment: Definitely add a rear fan. You want an fan that is also pulling out, not just blowing hot exhaust air into the case.

Comment: Keep your airflow clean. Pull at the front & push at the back, with sufficient space behind to allow escape [not in a cupboard, not against a wall]. If you can get sufficient throughput that way, then you can close off the silly holes at the top, which are really just there to ruin the airflow. Most PC cases have never been near a CFD designer. See https://superuser.com/a/1529892/347380 for pictures.