# What are Motherboard Fans?

Tags: motherboard

Lately, motherboards such as the MSI X570 ACE have these fans built into them. As I'm going to be building a new PC I am wondering why these fans exist in motherboard as previously older motherboards do not have them. As it is a mechanical (moving) part, it becomes another cause of concern where it may wear and tear/break if it is not durable or uses bearings that are substandard.

[image]

1. What is the purpose of these fans?
2. How durable are these fans?
3. If they are prone to wear and tear/stop working, can they be replaced or is the motherboard completely at risk if these fans stop working?
4. What is the expected lifespan of these fans?
5. Do these fans turn on all the time or only turn on when the temperature of the motherboard reaches a certain limit (just like how a PSU fan would behave)?

Comment: The answer to the first question should answer all your questions, the purpose of a fan built-into the motherboard, is to cool the ICs around the fan, that are part of the motherboard

Comment: In the not so recent past, active chipset coolers were normal. Just fyi.

Comment: Note that the motherboard in your picture has a partial "heat shield" designed to prevent components above the mobo like 24v video cards from contributing heat to the system board and vice-versa. that would however trap heat generated by the boards components close to it, which is also bad, so a fan is used to circulate that air and exchange it with air around the edges of the board. I had an asus sabertooth board once with a heat shield covering almost everything.

Comment: Why don't motherboard manufacturers use passive cooling instead? Such as having an aluminum block rather than a mechanical moving part which would be the fan. A german PC modder in reddit was able to replace his ASUS chipset fan to an aluminum one and it works.

Comment: @avg9957, passive cooling may in fact be sufficient, but it has lower thresholds than active, so it all depends on the degree of heat generation, the airflow in the case, etc. in still air finned heat-sinks perform increasingly poorly as the temperature increases. The heat-sink cannot just keep taking heat if its not evacuating it to air in a proportional manner. So what works for one situation may not work for all, and its often hard to measure the impact of a change like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. To circulate air to cool the chips that would otherwise get too hot and degrade.
2. It depends. Most likely standard consumer equipment. Most likely durable enough to last for the expected motherboard lifespan.
3. The motherboard may be at risk and heat up so it will at least shorten the useful lifetime of the motherboard.
4. Most likely it lasts about the expected useful life of the motherboard. It would not make economically sense to make it last say 10 or 20 years.
5. See the manual how it works.

Answer (score 1):

I'm only going to deal with point 1. The rest depends on how it's built & with what quality component etc.

Generic 'PC' cases have long been at best a random collection of bad airflow designs, random components & a rat's nest of wires interconnecting them. They are a CFD nightmare.

That fan structure is a [half-hearted] attempt to get some airflow through the machine - however, they only thought about the GPUs, the rest is just as random as ever. RAM is still facing across any potential airflow & the finished machine is still going to be strewn with wires. Any drive racking is likely to be in front of the whole thing, further confounding the air flow.

Pulled from my own answer at [Does the RPM of case fans make a big cooling difference?](https://superuser.com/questions/1529880/does-the-rpm-of-case-fans-make-a-big-cooling-difference) discussing the benefits of faster fans...

> So, just to be able to post some airflow designs to show how difficult
> it would be to make an accurate decision.
>
> Poor design…   Random airflow, no coherent flow design, some areas
> with no flow at all, CPU fans pulling air down towards the
> motherboard, RAM mounted across the airflow, wires all over the place
> interfering still further.
>
> Advantages of higher rate fans, debatable. You'd pull more air in &
> push more air out, but where it would go in the meantime & how much
> good it would do is a [CFD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_fluid_dynamics) nightmare.
>
> [image]
>
> Good design…   3 distinct, unconnected flow paths, all areas with
> flow, CPU fans pulling air through in a straight line, RAM mounted in
> the same line as the airflow, no stray wiring at all.
>
> Advantages of higher rate fans, none. They're not needed. The fans in
> this machine peak at 5000 rpm anyway.
>
> [image]
>
> Labels added, for anyone not familiar with this design.

To deal with questions 2 through 5 in one quick paragraph. Fans can last decades if they're well built. I've had machines running 24/7 for 10 years without the fans or anything else ever sleeping. if the machine runs cool enough - ie the airflow is well designed - you will never hear them.