# Any solution to high chipset temp

Tags: motherboard

I have Asus tuf x570 motherboard and the chipset temp in idle is 74c and in load 90 c. I changed the TIM for the cooler and used noctua thermal paste but no difference. I tried to put another fan but also no difference. The only one that prevent reach 100c is to leave case side door open!

any other solution ?

I have this case
https://www.raidmax.com/product_d.php?lang=en&tb=1&id=96

I moved my gpu to second slot and placed a 12in Fan at very fast speed on the chipset the temp went down only like 6c !!

From the author HWInfo display internal chipset temperature. here is a comparison with other tools. the max one is 63c

[image]

Comment: An additional fan doesn't help if the airflow is insufficient, which seems to be your problem.

Answer (score 0):

If leaving the side off is cooler than with it on, then the issue isn't (necessarily) with your fan, it's with your overall airflow.

First thing to check - just in case - is that your cooler fan is actually pulling air from the case & pushing it through the cooler, not vice versa (assuming a stock cooler setup) and that the fan is mounted the right way up. This may sound obvious, but fans have a specific orientation in which they function at their best.

Without knowing the case design, no-one can make specific recommendations, but based on an answer I did on [Does the RPM of case fans make a big cooling difference?](https://superuser.com/questions/1529880/does-the-rpm-of-case-fans-make-a-big-cooling-difference) consider this as a typical PC case design…

[image]

Because of the usually poor CFD design of these cases, airflow is often confused & restricted.
What you need is more airflow between A & B on the diagram. This will pass over your mobo, taking heat out of the case. Ideally, you want the same amount of air being pulled in at the front as is being expelled at the back - this way the fans are in balance & not fighting each other. The fan at C is less important, though in extreme circumstances may be slightly beneficial.
Some modern cooler designs use a vertical fan which may help direct hot air towards the rear fan at B.
The fan at D is usually part of the PSU itself & not under your control.

Comment: CPU temps are fine I am talking about the chipset in x570. How high consider safe ?

Comment: I've no idea, look at your mobo spec. Your issue is still being able to remove hot air. Blowing it round inside the case obviously isn't working. You can pretty much just remove the word 'CPU' from this & the answer still applies.

Comment: 95°C is the normal maximum temperature for a chipset. The average should be around 77°C-80°C. It sounds like you need some more case fans, or to increase the speed of the ones you have, if you have a fan speed controller.

Comment: @spikey_richie - I didn't want to throw out random numbers - there's nothing on my machine hotter than 50° except the Northbridge, which seems to settle around 65°. I can monitor about 35 sensors on this machine.

Comment: From my experience, the numbers I posted seem reasonable.

Comment: They may be, but based on what? Empirically, mine are nowhere near those figure. I have a sample set of one, as the other machines here have more basic sensor readouts, standard CPU/GPU temps only.

Comment: @Tetsujin googling I found some cases like mine

Comment: @spikey_richie Thanks can you help me please if there is a safe shutdown option in the bios menus to shutdown if the temp went above 90 c so the motherboard did not burn something else or it only available for CPU temp ?

Comment: Why not get the airflow fixed, rather than looking for mitigation for not fixing it? That's a bit like asking the car mechanic to fix the horn because the brakes don't work.

Comment: @Tetsujin wrong example I just want to make sure the reading I am getting is correct first.

Answer (score 0):

My Z590 was idling at 85C.  I improved air flow and turned off unused PCH features in BIOS, WIFI an the second ethernet port, and got it to 65C.  The real key was a 55mm high right angle duct for the bottom fan that I got on EBAY.  With the duct the bottom, 120 mm, fan blows directly on the chipset.  My rig is also much more stable, especially using Thunderbolt 4.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: If possible say what features you disabled in detail. The cooler you used like model name with a picture

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I solved the problem:

- I used Innovation Cooling Graphite Thermal Pad
- I tested with the chipset fan cover on and off and found 10c difference better without the plastic cover so I remove it

Result: max temp was about 75c.
Note: This was common issue in this model with many complain about it in the net.