# Is there a way to force FFmpeg to use a specific CPU?

Tags: ffmpeg

I am using FFMpeg, latest version self compiled in Windows 10.

I have a dual CPU Xeon system.Is there any way to limit use of FFMpeg to the second CPU only?

Comment: Why specifically the second CPU? For x264 encoding you can set it to be `threads=1` which _should_ restrict FFmpeg to a single CPU.

Comment: I see absolutely no benefit in limiting to any specific CPU or core. The OS's job is to distribute resources as efficiently [& speedily] as possible. User interference rarely gains anything & usually makes things worse.

Comment: Because my primary CPU runs about 7 - 10 degrees hotter on any given core and I've replaced the thermal paste with the same method as the second one and didn't help.  Both still ended up with the same separation in idle temps.  Figured if I could force the second CPU then would have more breathing room temp wise.  Going to assume from the responses that this isn't possible?

Comment: Dual Xeons always tend to run like that - this is mine right now, under no load… https://i.stack.imgur.com/SF4eB.png There are several identical machines in the building, all exhibit the same phenomenon, except one older machine with a side-by-side CPU layout - https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ykdrz.png All the others have a staggered layout, so the 2nd CPU gets some of the warm air off the first.  If I'm running them hard, they never get over 80°, so it's never an issue [proctHot is 100°, so I'm nowhere near that] I just wouldn't worry about it at all.

Comment: My CPUs are side by side with 6 fans across the case blowing air equally.  Maybe the CPU isn't from a good batch?  My second identical machine but with Windows 2016 both CPUs idle around the same 36 degrees or so.  My processors being older X5680 have a max vendor listed temp of 78.5.  CPU 0 being in the 50's doesn't leave a lot of room.  I can override Dell's fan speeds but only mid speed and super fast speed and nothing in between.  SpeedFan kind of messes up my system on reboot so hesitate to use it.  Built in fan control doesn't seem to panic when the temps are running in the low 80's.

Comment: Your info is wrong on ProcHot for those. It's 98°. That's what all the duals here are [or same family, Westmere, different speeds] The one with even temperatures is 1 gen older, Nehalem. Is your case design a straight-through airflow, or one of those usual PC cases with nightmare CFD?  See https://superuser.com/a/1529892/347380 for what I mean. The top pic is the standard terrible PC airflow design, the bottom is what this building is full of;) You can see the staggered CPU offset in the lower 3rd