# Enhancing the cooling system of my PC

Tags: fan, cooling

I have an RTX 3090 , aorus b550 master , AMD Ryzen 5800X and nzxt h510. I am looking to improve the cooling system through adding two Fan cases in the in front  position of the case. I am planning to buy 2 cooler master sickleflow 120 argb fans. I am planning to put them such that they draw in air. So in general, is this a correct plan to enhance and decrease the hardware temperature ?  Or do I need to buy other fans or change their positions , ..etc. ? Note that I already have a fan installed in the vents at the top of case.

Comment: The biggest problem with most PC cases is not the number of fans, it's the complete lack of CFD design in the airflow - https://superuser.com/a/1529892/347380

Comment: Before you add any extra fans, check how the current ones are installed.  E.g are both pulling air out of the case? Also, what is your goal, cool the CPU more? Get more colder air next tot the graphics card? ... That will help you think about the air flow (as Tetsujin already meansted).  Also, how do you cool the CPU? If I would put my system in that case (Aorus B550, 5800X, bequiet4pro) then the fans and the cooler would be in a weird agle if I used this case