# Is there any evidence that running PC components at temperatures higher than +80c actually affect the lifespan of said components like CPU or GPU?

Tags: cpu, gpu, temperature, lifespan

Many people say you should keep your computer hardware's temperature below 70-80c by claiming it increases longevity of hardware components. If that is really the case, then why hardware manufacturers like **Intel**, **AMD**, and **Nvidia** state that, for example, some of their GPU products can handle higher temperatures up to **105c** consistently with no issues?
Even **AMD** points out that their product will run **"perfectly safe"** on **95c** and lower.

So, if hardware manufacturers have already conducted those tests on seemingly harsh temperatures to ensure their quality of products, then why people assume it is bad at this point?

According to **[ASUS: Will CPU lifespan or stability be affected under high temperature?](https://www.asus.com/us/support/FAQ/1041954/)**, their statement was "As long as the temperature is lower than the original standard (105 or 100 Celsius degrees) regulated by Intel, the CPU lifespan will not **be affected**."

Comment: Your question title & body do not match. One is asking for evidence, the other for why humans choose to believe what they do in the face of this evidence.

Comment: Many people say you should keep your computer hardware's temperture below 70-80c    .....  The average ambient temperature of a computer (some parts higher some lower) is best below 45 degrees C.  The closer to room temperature the better.  My CPUs (3 machines) run under 50 degrees C running 24x7

Comment: Is there an expected lifespan given for the component?

Comment: You're focusing on only the ratings and reliability of the expensive components of a PC, i.e. the CPU and GPU. But what about the assortment of auxiliary chips and active & passive components on the motherboard? The typical consumer-grade motherboard is likely to have components not even industrial-rated for 85 degrees Celsius. So perhaps your CPU can withstand the heat, but don't expect your entire PC to outlast it. You would need to look for better-than-industrial-rated components to match that 105C temp rating.

Comment: @sawdust - you'd need heat dissipation even worse than most PC cases [which are admittedly mostly poor] to raise the mobo temperatures to anywhere near those of the CPU/GPU etc.

Comment: @Tetsujin -- The typical PC desktop is designed to have the CPU "cooler" disperse hot air in various directions (depending on the heatsink design). The fan blows outside air over the heatsink, and that heated air is allowed to disperse throughout the case (and heat up everything else). Poor or no air circulation can lead to (hot) dead zones within the case. Efficient extraction of that hot air is typically compromised by the PC case design (e.g. it was never a cross-flow layout).

Comment: @sawdust - you mean a bit like this? https://superuser.com/a/1529892/347380

Answer (score 0):

**[Logical fallacy: Argument from incredulity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_from_incredulity).**

"I can't believe something could stand those temperatures constantly, so therefore this must be false."

Never underestimate the power of human 'belief' in the face of all evidence to the contrary.
The evidence, of course, is implicit. No manufacturer would guarantee a product that could easily be run outside its tested operating parameters, causing failure… or if they did, it wouldn't be for long before the knowledge caught up.

Manufacturers test things to destruction then assign values inside which 99.9% [or some high number] of products can survive indefinitely.
I've seen inside facilities such as this [I used to work for a major multinational electronics manufacturer & have visited the factory]. They had a machine that would bend a wire back & forth until it broke. One like a massive tumble dryer, 20ft tall, that would carry products to the top, then let them fall to the bottom… to see how long the case would survive abuse. They spend a lot of money on this - which is cheaper in the long run than guaranteeing 'guesswork'.

Answer (score 0):

"People" often repeat what they hear from other "people", whether its true of not.  Alternatively, "people" repeat what they think they here, hence the game [telephone](https://www.wikihow.com/Play-the-Telephone-Game).  Words and meanings get lost or misunderstood.

Manufacturers do rigorous testing of their products.  If they say their product can handle a certain temperature, odds are it will.  If it doesnt, then they are likely to lose money on refunding or replacing defective products.

Answer (score -1):

Pick a random set of datasheet for electronics components and check the max temperature they are guaranteed to work (reliably!) at.

You will find that the temperatures vary wildly; some are ok above 65 °C others not.

Personally I consider 'normal electronics' that cannot be held for more than a few seconds to be prone to fail earlier that expected.

*Personal experience from some 40 years of using computers and related hardware*

Comment: So, not liking the truth? ;-)