# CPU running at 100 degrees is my CPU overclocked?

Tags: cpu, fan, cooling, temperature

I bought a pre-built PC a couple of months ago. It's working well, but the fans can get very loud. Because of this, I thought I'd check the temperature using the Predator Sense bloat ware that came with the PC and when playing a game (any game), it's hitting 100 degrees C.

I've also verified this temperature with NZXT CAM.

Looking at task manager, I can see the CPU speed go up to 4.0GHz while the base speed is 2.1GHz, is this normal or does this mean it's been overclocked?

The PC came from a basic computer shop (Curry's UK) so not sure if there's an issue with cooling given that it sits at 100 degrees while playing games and only reduces by a few degrees if I set the fan RPM very high (and very loud).

I have nothing but the browser open at the minute and it's sitting at 56 degrees now (I think this is fine for idle?), but the speed in task manager is still around 3.8GHz.

The room is usually cool as I don't like a hot room anyway so there's no issue with ambient temperatures.

[image]

Here's an image of the internals. Keeping the side cover off does help reduce the temps from 100 degrees to 70-80 degrees.

Other than those 2 fans (and the GPU fans) there's one at the front but there's not a lot of air flow there (it's also at the bottom so only the GPU really benefits from this.

[image]

Comment: what is your CPU model? that kind of behavior (frequency boosting) is common for many chips. we cant tell about your's yet though.

Comment: @FrankThomas - That information information is in the screenshot

Comment: [your cpu](https://www.intel.com.au/content/www/au/en/products/sku/134592/intel-core-i712700f-processor-25m-cache-up-to-4-90-ghz/specifications.html) can actually run upt to 4.9GHz - the fact that it's hitting 100 degrees probably means either a cheap cooler (probably the stock cooler) or poorly installed cooler

Comment: “Looking at task manager, I can see the CPU speed go up to 4.0GHz while the base speed is 2.1GHz, is this normal or does this mean it's been overclocked?” - No; It’s not overclocked unless you consider the boost frequency to be a form of overclocking. But your CPU is also being thermally throttled.

Answer (score 1):

Your CPU's specs can be found at https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/134592/intel-core-i712700f-processor-25m-cache-up-to-4-90-ghz.html

You will see that its maximum frequency is 4.9GHz, so its not overclocked.   You will also see it has a maximum turbo power of 180W - which is quite a lot to cool.

In fact, your computer is not overclocked, its throttling - ie the CPU is limiting itself due to its inability to dissipate enough heat.    https://www.overclock.net/threads/intel-core-i7-12700f-high-temperature.1799045/ is a useful read - there are plausible claims the Intel stock cooler can't handle over 100W sustained.

Its also worth pointing out this is an "F" series CPU, not a "K" series CPU.  Generally its the K series CPU's that can be overclocked.

Comment: +1 In short you need better cooling. You also need to check whether the case design is allowing sufficient air throughput. This is probably not Curry's speciality, but it wouldn't go amiss to have a word with someone there & see if they have suggestions. Technically, it would be tough to prove whose 'fault' this is but you might find a young enthusiastic assistant who gives a damn. Chat them up, don't yell at them ;))

Comment: Taking the side cover off the case improves the temps a lot (80 degrees currently). Not ideal but it does prove it's a cooling issue.

Comment: This is a big issue in PC case [lack of] design. Most PC cases I have ever seen are an absolute CFD disaster. See https://superuser.com/a/1529892/347380 You have to try your best to get air *through* it, which the way they're built just confounds at every step.