# Dust affects most desktop computers, so why don't we just hang motherboards upside down?

Tags: motherboard, cooling

I had an idea for a possible way to avoid dust buildup in PC computers: Why don't we just hang motherboards upside down (open casket) below desks or the ceiling itself?  This might even have some nice cooling properties (the same reason petrol cars have a bare open bottom).

The idea is simple: with an open bottom, any dust would simply fall to the ground via gravity.  What practical reasons would make this a bad idea or infeasible?

Comment: Dust would just settle on the other side. Motherboards exposed with no cooling would overheat. Most PC cases are already hopelessly designed, making airflow a real issue. Passive cooling would probably be even worse. Where would you you put all your peripherals… drives, GPU etc? Do you just nail them up next to it or leave them to swing in the breeze? My own machine actually has a vertical motherboard. It still all needs blowing through a couple of times a year. CPU fans will pull dust through no matter what the orientation.

Comment: BTW, cars don't have an 'open bottom' these days, they're almost sealed from underneath compared to 30 years ago. They also have big cooling radiators at the front & a fan to pull a lot of air through.

Comment: Dust is also attracted by static (electric fields). if your idea had merit someone would have suggested it a long time ago.

Comment: @Tetsujin I don't mean "no cooling"... I mean the current motherboards with the current cooling systems (fan over the processor, one more fan on the side)... only different thing here would be that the motherboard would be orientated so that the processor and fan are facing downwards.

Comment: "any dust would simply fall to the ground via gravity" - No; This actually would not happen.

Comment: Seán - 'current cooling' includes forced air over the entire surface, depending on how good the design is. It's not only the CPU that needs cooling. See https://superuser.com/a/1529892/347380

Comment: @Tetsujin I'm aware of that, I was basically just listing out the fan configuration on a lot of consumer PCs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CPU would still need a fan, meaning it would still create some kind of airflow across your motherboard which would still potentially leave dust on it.

I'm not sure why you'd want to prevent dust from settling on the motherboard, of all things. The bigger issue is dust clogging up the heatsinks, which reduces the effectiveness of the heatsinks.

Sure, the VRMs *might* be cooler because of less dust, but if your VRMs got hot enough to where it mattered, they would have a fan. In that case, dust would still settle on the VRM heatsinks.

It's a good attempt at fixing an issue, but it's neither feasible nor would it actually significantly help.